# What is going wrong with GraphLayout?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I suspect this is just a bug in Mathematica. Here is the same graph embedded with different options for GraphLayout:

```
edges =
{
UndirectedEdge[1, 2],
UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
UndirectedEdge[3, 5],
UndirectedEdge[4, 7],
UndirectedEdge[4, 8],
UndirectedEdge[5, 6],
UndirectedEdge[5, 7]
};
{Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium], 
 Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium]}
```

The output is shown below.

[image: Output]

The two graphs appear to have different connectivity. What is up with this?

Comment: add the options `EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"` and `VertexLabels -> "Name"` to both `Graph`s  to avoid overlapping edges.

Comment: Ahh, the EdgeShapeFunction is what I need I suppose. In my actual case rather than MWE, I did have labelled vertices, but it still didn't occur to me that Mathematica was drawing the edges to exactly overlap. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use GridEmbedding for anything else but a `GridGraph`. It's a dumb method that puts vertices on a grid in the order they appear in the vertex list. It will almost always result in overlapping edges unless your graph has a very specific structure and vertex ordering (i.e. it's what GridGraph generates, possibly with some missing edges)

Comment: The "CurvedArc" option is pretty neat; however, where is it documented? I went through the v12 documentation and it doesn't appear at all as near as I can tell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edges `4 <-> 7` and  `4 <-> 8` overlap in the first graph. You can make the edges curved using the option `EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"` to avoid overlapping edges:

```
Row[{Graph[edges, 
    GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  Graph[edges, 
    GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"], 
  Graph[edges, 
    GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  Graph[edges, 
    GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, used `"CurvedArc"` only for the edges `4 <-> 7` and  `4 <-> 8`:

```
Graph[edges,
 GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding", ImageSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {UndirectedEdge[4, _] -> "CurvedArc"}]
```

[image]